# Having issues with a program to input multiple numbers from the user, till the user types “Done". To compute their average and print the results

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here is how the program is supposed to work. The user would input something like this and the output would give them the answer.
Input:
1
2
2
1
Done

Output:
1.5

So far I was able to come up with the input question and got it to loop until you put Done.

```
nums = [] # Empty list.

while True:
    num = input("Enter number, or Done  to end:")
if num == "Done":

    break
else:

    nums.append(int(num))
```

I don't know how to make the program perform the calculation to print out the average. I am very new to programming in python and I would appreciate any help I can get on fixing this program. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: `sum()` and `len()`

Comment: you have a big indentation problem.

Comment: `print (float(sum(nums)) / float(len(nums)))` to add up all values and divide by length of the list. Note what happens if you don't use `float`.

Comment: can't see any idea when you can simply ask for numbers and just read it

Comment: @roganjosh in Python 3 - that's not a concern... although it's handy to know if using Python 2... although you don't need both to be floats... just one is sufficient... or you can even do `sum(nums, 0.0) / len(nums)`

Comment: @JonClements doh, I skipped the `3.x` tag in my mind when I went back for the edit. Still, gives some further reading :)

Comment: @donte you should accept the answer if it answers your question. It not, please indicate what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Break while loop when 'Done' is the input, else save the number as float. This throws an error if you try to enter 'finish'. Finally calculate and print the Average.

```
nums = [] # Empty list.

while True:
    num = input("Enter number, or Done  to end:")
    if num == "Done": # This has to be tested inside the while loop
        break
    # Only append after testing for 'Done'
    nums.append(float(num)) # Ensure valid input by convert it into the desired type.

print('average: %s' % (sum(nums) / len(nums)))
```

It is a good practice to give the user useful error messages, when some input is not as the program needs it. It can save the user lots of trouble. If you just want to tell the user what the problem was when an invalid input is given, you can do it with a try statement as below:

```
nums = [] # Empty list.

while True:
    num = input("Enter number, or Done  to end:")
    if num == "Done":
        break
    try:
        nums.append(float(num))
    except Exception:
        print('Please enter a number. Input "%s" will be ignored.' % num)

print('average: %s' % (sum(nums) / len(nums)))
```